# C# WPF Checkbox with null value?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, nullreferenceexception

I am currently making a GUI in WPF, and am working on a page intended to create and configure message rooms but the following code below

```
else if (Password_Enabled.IsChecked == true && Password.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            return false; 
        }
```

appears with an error of

Password_Enabled.IsChecked 'Password_Enabled.IsChecked' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

My Xaml for the CheckBox appears as follows

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Password_Enabled" IsChecked="False" Content="Password Enabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="Password_Enabled_Checked" Unchecked="Password_Disabled_Checked" Margin="10,5,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

I've searched online, but with errors like these it's standardised, I know it means that the checkbox is being treated as null. But while searching through my code haven't found anything stating why, any help on this would be much appreciated, thank you.

## Edit

My FullCode for the Page C# is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChatRoom
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for New_Server.xaml
   /// </summary>
 public partial class New_Server : Page
{
    public New_Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Owner.Text = Global_Class.GetUsername(Environment.UserName);
    }
    public static string ChosenAddress = "";

    private bool CheckValidCredentials()
    {
        List<string> IllegalCharacters = new List<string>() { ",", "|", "\\", "/", ".", "?", "\"", "<", ">", ":" };
        bool Illegal = false;
        if (ServerName.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (string Check in IllegalCharacters)
        {
            if (ServerName.Text.Contains(Check))
            {
                Illegal = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Illegal)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (Password_Enabled.IsChecked == true && Password.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else if (ChosenAddress == "")
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    public void SetMakeServer()
    {
        if (CheckValidCredentials())
        {
            MakeServer.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MakeServer.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
    private void Public_Server_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This Server Will Be Open to everyone in the College, Please Untick if you wish to change this.");
        CheckValidCredentials();
    }
    private void Password_Enabled_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Password.IsEnabled = true;
        OneTimePass.IsEnabled = true;
        SetMakeServer();
    }
    private void Password_Disabled_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Password.IsEnabled = false;
        OneTimePass.IsEnabled = false;
        SetMakeServer();
    }

    private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Server_Selection());
    }

    private void ServerDirectorySet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fbd = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ChosenAddress = fbd.SelectedPath;
                ServerDirectoryDisplay.Content = "Location: " + ChosenAddress;
            }
            else
            {
                ChosenAddress = "";
                SetMakeServer();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ServerName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetMakeServer();
    }

    private void Password_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetMakeServer();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You run that code before `InitializeComponent()` (called from the constructor in the codebehind) has finished running.

Comment: @canton7
That's what I thought as well, this is part of a function to check for correct inputs, 
This is the code I used for the (Page) Main Function tho
        'public New_Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Owner.Text = Global_Class.GetUsername(Environment.UserName);
        }'
I don't even call the function, it's caused by a button but still acts odd for a reason.

Comment: Post your full code then please -- [mcve]

Comment: @canton7 Just posted

Comment: Right. I bet that `Public_Server` is a checkbox which is checked when it is constructed (in InitializeComponent). It's checked after `Public_Server_Checked` is registered, but before `Password_Enabled` is constructed. So it does happen because `Public_Server_Checked` is run before InitializeComponent has finished running.

Comment: None of this would have happened if you would invest time in making this in MvvM with Binding. What forced you to use Page in the first place?

Comment: Ahh thanks, just moved around bits in the xaml code, and moved into a logical order, that seemed to do it, Thank You.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I haven't been coding as much in wpf for long, but the main method I learnt to use and start off with is page, and it's just what I'm used to at the moment, open to suggestions tho, do you know where I could find tutorials on "MvvM"?

Comment: Certainly, first place [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_hooking_up_views.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InitializeComponent has to finish before you interact with anything on the UI. If you try to access visual elements in your code before WPF has finished initializing them you'll get the null errors.

Comment: I figured this way something could be marked as an answer so if somebody comes across this it's right there.